# Proof on if a set is discrete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-verification

I would like to know how well I answered the following proof: was it concise? Was it elaborate/rigorous? Did I use incorrect notation?

I would also like to know if the set is a $T_{1}$ space, such that every pair of distinct points contains an open ball not containing any other point. By definition, I suppose it is such a space, but I would like verification.

Onward,

Prove the following metric space $M$ is discrete: $$D(x, y) :\begin{cases} 0, &\text{ if }x=y \\ 1, &\text{ if }x\ne y \end{cases}$$

The metric is discrete if every subset is open. This needs proof.

Suppose there exists a metric space $x, y \in  M$. Define $$x \in E, y \in F : E \cap F = \emptyset$$ Also, there are distinct points such that $x \not= y$, otherwise the proof is trivial.

Define E to contain a neighborhood $B_{r}(x) : y \not\in B_{r}(x) : x \not= y$.

Since $y \not\in  E$ and $E$ is not closed, ${x}$ is an isolated point of $E$. QED.

Comment: In your proof it is very unclear what you are aiming at. You have to start with an arbitrary set and show that it is open. Alternatively, you could show that $\{x\}$ is open for each $x\in M$, and then deduce that all sets are open. Instead you suppose there is a subset $M$, but $M$ is the metric space you are working in. Then you "define" sets $E,F$ without actually defining them. If you mean open sets, then you had to justify why they can be chosen to be disjoint.

Comment: For the notation do this:  
`$\begin{cases}
0, &\text{ if }x=y \\
1, &\text{ if }x\ne y
\end{cases}$` to get $\begin{cases}
0, &\text{ if }x=y \\
1, &\text{ if }x\ne y
\end{cases}$

Comment: @StefanH. I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: You are aware that metric spaces are always $T_1$?

Comment: No, I wasn't...@HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find your proof unclear. I would write it as follows:

**Claim:** $(M,D)$ is a discrete metric space.

**Proof:** The conditions for $D$ to be a metric are obviously satisfied. Let $x\in M$, then the open ball
$$B_x\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \left\{y\in M|D(x,y)<\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$
constains only the point $x$ itself. Thus $\{x\}$ is open for every $x\in M$, and $M$ is discrete. QED

Also $(M,D)$ is $T_1$. In fact it is at least normal (i.e. $T_4$). I'm not familiar with the higher separability axioms.

Comment: Doesn't that imply $y$ is contained in the open ball, since $D(x, y) < {1 \over 2}$?

Comment: @Jossie In my proof, $y$ doesn't denote a distinct element of $M$.

Comment: What does it denote? Otherwise, I am misinterpreting your symbols, because what I am reading is "y is a point in M".

Comment: Like every metric space, it’s $T_6$: normal, $T_1$, and closed sets are $G_\delta$-sets.

Comment: @Jossie Yes, I was defining a set, so it means "the set of all points in $M$ with distance less than one half from $x$".